# Can transaction chain improve performance for reading on follower?

Tags: opendaylight

I noticed that transactions started on the shard follower are significantly slower than on the shard leader. However, while write operations are 5-10 times slower, the read operations are slower 1000 times.
I read mostly the same data that I just wrote but in separate transactions. Can using of transaction chain improve the read performance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions on a follower will be slower b/c every operation (read, write etc) has to go to the leader for strong consistency, which incurs network and serialization latencies. A transaction chain won't improve that.